# Adjoint Operators

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$

Hi, Im kinda stuck with this problem.

Let $ V = \mathbb{C}[X] $ be polynomials with complex coefficients and define

$ \langle f(x) \mid g(x)\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(0). $

Also define the two operators on $ V $,

$ L_{1}(f(x))= f(x+1) + f(x-1) \quad and \quad L_{2}(f(x))= (x+1)f(x).  $

I want to show that $ L_{1} $ doesn't have an adjoint operator $L_{1}^\dag$, i.e

$ \langle f(x) \mid L_1(g(x)) \rangle = \langle L_{1}^\dag (f(x)) \mid g(x). \rangle $

And that $ L_{2}^\dag $ exsists.

My work for $ L_{2}^\dag $ this far;

$ L_2 $ is hermitian or self-adjoint, since $ \overline{(x+1)} = (x+1)$, thus

$$   \langle f(x) \mid L_2(g(x)) \rangle = \langle L_{2}( f(x)) \mid g(x) \rangle. $$

Does this reasoning seem any right?

And for $ L_1 $,

$ \langle f(x) \mid L_1(g(x)) \rangle =  \langle f(x) \mid g(x+1) + g(x-1) \rangle = \langle f(x) \mid g(x+1) \rangle + \langle f(x) \mid g(x-1) \rangle = $

$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\overline{f^{(n)}(0)}g^{(n)}(-1) $

Now Im stuck, I don't know how to show that it doesn't exist such operator.

Any help is muy appriciated!<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle f(x) \mid x^{n}\rangle = \overline{f^{(n)}(0)}$

$\langle 1 \mid g(x)\rangle = g(0)$

$\langle 1 \mid L_1(x^{n}) \rangle = \langle 1 \mid (x+1)^{n} + (x-1)^{n} \rangle = (-1)^{n} + 1^{n}$

Let $h(x) =  L_{1}^{\dagger} (1)$. We have:

$  \langle L_{1}^{\dagger} (1) \mid x^{n} \rangle = (-1)^{n} + 1^{n}$

$h^{(n)}(0) =(-1)^{n} + 1^{n}$

The function $h$ is clearly not a polynomial, even tough it is defined as $L_{1}^{\dagger} (1)$, and $1$ is a constant polynomial. Therefore $L_{1}^{\dagger}$ is not a well defined operator on the space $V$ of polynomials with complex coefficients (by Taylor series we may compute $h(x) = e^{x} + e^{-x}$).

It can be shown that it is not even well-defined in the space of analytic functions, but this is more complex. The idea is the same tough: construct an object in your space such that the adjoint operator, when applied to your object, would make an object that is not in that space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!